# How to display same text in two deferent websites

Tags: html, xml

I have 5 deferent contents and I want to display it in two deferent websites. Is there is any possible way to do this?

I tried XML but it shows only in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content that you want to be displayed on multiple websites in a .php file without the   tags, as the file your going to call this from should already have this. For example well call this content.php

Now you're going to change these files to .php as you need to use some php code to call this file for example

The file that the content is in is in the following directory, website/includes/content.php

Now lets say the websites your calling it from are in different directory's e.g.

website/firstweb/index.php
website/secondweb/index.php (you must rename your index.html to index.php

Now all you need to do is put this snippet in the area you would like it to be displayed

```
<?php
     require_once'../includes/content.php'
?>
```

What this is doing is going back one directory "../" and then accessing the file through the includes folder

Hope this makes sense to you, but this is one of the easiest ways I know of doing this.